# Update SQL in Access VBA -- Updating Table Values From Another Table

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access-2013

I'm fairly new to Access VBA and SQL coding. So far, I've been able to find most of the answers to issues I've had by using the internet. I'm currently trying to write some code in MS Access (2013) VBA that updates the data in one table from another table in the same database when a particular form closes.

I've worked out several errors so far, but I'm stuck on a syntax error in the "UPDATE" for SQLReplace. There could be other errors that I don't know about yet, but I'm not sure. Any help/Guidance would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks!

```
Private Sub Form_Close()

Dim SQLMove As String
Dim SQLReplace As String

Dim CountyCaseType As String
Dim CaseNumber As String
Dim County As String
Dim FirstName As String
Dim MiddleName As String
Dim LastName As String
Dim Facility As String
Dim VOL As String
Dim Diagnosis As String
Dim AppearanceWaived As String
Dim Dismissed As String
Dim HearingResults As String
Dim Disposition As String
Dim DOB As String
Dim Minor As String
Dim Sex As String
Dim ClerkName As String
Dim Judge As String
Dim CourtDate As String


CountyCaseType = "Tables!tblTemp.CountyCaseType.Value"
CaseNumber = "Tables!tblTemp.CaseNumber.Value"
County = "Tables!tblTemp.County.Value"
FirstName = "Tables!tblTemp.FirstName.Value"
MiddleName = "Tables!tblTemp.MiddleName.Value"
LastName = "Tables!tblTemp.LastName.Value"
Facility = "Tables!tblTemp.Facility.Value"
VOL = "Tables!tblTemp.VOL.Value"
Diagnosis = "Tables!tblTemp.Diagnosis.Value"
AppearanceWaived = "Tables!tblTemp.AppearanceWaived.Value"
Dismissed = "Tables!tblTemp.Dismissed.Value"
HearingResults = "Tables!tblTemp.HearingResults.Value"
Disposition = "Tables!tblTemp.Disposition.Value"
DOB = "Tables!tblTemp.DOB.Value"
Minor = "Tables!tblTemp.Minor.Value"
Sex = "Tables!tblTemp.Sex.Value"
ClerkName = "Tables!tblTemp.Clerk.Value"
Judge = "Tables!tblTemp.Judge.Value"
CourtDate = "Tables!tblTemp.CourtDate.Value"

SQLMove = "INSERT INTO tblCalendar SELECT * FROM tblTemp"
SQLReplace = "UPDATE tblCalendar " & _
                     "SET tblCalendar.CountyCaseType.Value = CountyCaseType, " & _
                     "    tblCalendar.CaseNumber.Value = CaseNumber, " & _
                     "    tblCalendar.County.Value = County, " & _
                     "    tblCalendar.FirstName.Value = FirstName, " & _
                     "    tblCalendar.MiddleName.Value = MiddleName, " & _
                     "    tblCalendar.LastName.Value = LastName, " & _
                     "    tblCalendar.Facility.Value = Facility, " & _
                     "    tblCalendar.VOL.Value = VOL, " & _
                     "    tblCalendar.Diagnosis.Value = Diagnosis, " & _
                     "    tblCalendar.AppearanceWaived.Value = AppearanceWaived, " & _
                     "    tblCalendar.Dismissed.Value = Dismissed, " & _
                     "    tblCalendar.HearingResults.Value = HearingResults, " & _
                     "    tblCalendar.Disposition.Value = Disposition, " & _
                     "    tblCalendar.DOB.Value = DOB, " & _
                     "    tblCalendar.Minor.Value = Minor, " & _
                     "    tblCalendar.Sex.Value = Sex, " & _
                     "    tblCalendar.ClerkName.Value = Clerk, " & _
                     "    tblCalendar.Judge.Value = Judge, " & _
                     "FROM tblTemp " & _
                     "Where 'CourtDate = tblCalendar.CourtDate.Value'"
DoCmd.SetWarnings False
DoCmd.RunSQL (SQLMove)
DoCmd.RunSQL (SQLReplace)
DoCmd.SetWarnings True
End Sub
```

Comment: Maybe u should post the error message?

Comment: Rethink your processing. You update from the very table you just imported? Also, `FROM` clause is not allowed in Access SQL update statements. Look into `UPDATE ... INNER JOIN`.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback! I'm using tbltemp in connection with a form that I have -- I don't want tblCalendar to be directly linked to the forml. The process is: 
1. All Information is stored in tblCalendar
2. When a particular form is opened, I have code that tells access to copy data from the tblCalendar into tblTemp,  but it only grabs the data that is associated with a particular court date.
3. Anyone using the form can now view and edit only the information for the court date they indicated (and they can add additional data).

So far, everything works. My issue is going the other way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several potential errors in your code:

1. You do not need to add `.Value` to the end of an attribute to get its actual value.
2. As you are working directly in Access, you to not need the `Tables!` part either. That is the syntax used when dealing with recordsets. For example, write `tblTemp.CountyCaseType` instead of `Tables!tblTemp.CountyCaseType.Value`
3. The values of your variables are not in the SQL string. You have to concatenate them to the SQLReplace String using *[&]*. For example, write

   ```
   SQLReplace = "UPDATE tblCalendar " & _
                    "SET tblCalendar.CountyCaseType = " & CountyCaseType & ", " & _
                    "    tblCalendar.CaseNumber = " & CaseNumber & ", " & _
                    ....
   ```
4. As @AlanHadsell pointed out, remove the single quotes from the `WHERE` clause.

   ```
   Where 'CourtDate = tblCalendar.CourtDate.Value'
   ```

   should be

   ```
   WHERE CourtDate = tblCalendar.CourtDate
   ```

   But as I said in *3)* `CourTDate` is a `String` variable, so it needs to be concatenated. Your final `WHERE` clause should be:

   ```
   "WHERE " & CourtDate & " = tblCalendar.CourtDate"
   ```
5. You don't need the `FROM tblTemp` clause in the SQLReplace String.
6. **EDIT**: As @Parfait pointed out, tblTemp does not exist in scope of the SQLReplace statement. You should do an `INNER JOIN` to fix that:

   ```
   UPDATE tblCalendar INNER JOIN tblTemp ON tblCalendar.CourtDate = tblTemp.CourtDate SET ...
   ```

After fixing everything, your final code should look like:

```
Private Sub Form_Close()

    Dim SQLMove As String
    Dim SQLReplace As String

    Dim CountyCaseType As String
    Dim CaseNumber As String
    Dim County As String
    Dim FirstName As String
    Dim MiddleName As String
    Dim LastName As String
    Dim Facility As String
    Dim VOL As String
    Dim Diagnosis As String
    Dim AppearanceWaived As String
    Dim Dismissed As String
    Dim HearingResults As String
    Dim Disposition As String
    Dim DOB As String
    Dim Minor As String
    Dim Sex As String
    Dim ClerkName As String
    Dim Judge As String
    Dim CourtDate As String


    CountyCaseType = "tblTemp.CountyCaseType"
    CaseNumber = "tblTemp.CaseNumber"
    County = "tblTemp.County"
    FirstName = "tblTemp.FirstName"
    MiddleName = "tblTemp.MiddleName"
    LastName = "tblTemp.LastName"
    Facility = "tblTemp.Facility"
    VOL = "tblTemp.VOL"
    Diagnosis = "tblTemp.Diagnosis"
    AppearanceWaived = "tblTemp.AppearanceWaived"
    Dismissed = "tblTemp.Dismissed"
    HearingResults = "tblTemp.HearingResults"
    Disposition = "tblTemp.Disposition"
    DOB = "tblTemp.DOB"
    Minor = "tblTemp.Minor"
    Sex = "tblTemp.Sex"
    ClerkName = "tblTemp.Clerk"
    Judge = "tblTemp.Judge"
    CourtDate = "tblTemp.CourtDate"

    SQLMove = "INSERT INTO tblCalendar SELECT * FROM tblTemp"
    SQLReplace = "UPDATE tblCalendar " & _
                 "INNER JOIN tblTemp ON tblCalendar.CourtDate = tblTemp.CourtDate " & _
                         "SET tblCalendar.CountyCaseType = " & CountyCaseType & ", " & _
                         "    tblCalendar.CaseNumber = " & CaseNumber & ", " & _
                         "    tblCalendar.County = " & County & ", " & _
                         "    tblCalendar.FirstName = " & FirstName & ", " & _
                         "    tblCalendar.MiddleName = " & MiddleName & ", " & _
                         "    tblCalendar.LastName = " & LastName & ", " & _
                         "    tblCalendar.Facility = " & Facility & ", " & _
                         "    tblCalendar.VOL = " & VOL & ", " & _
                         "    tblCalendar.Diagnosis = " & Diagnosis & ", " & _
                         "    tblCalendar.AppearanceWaived = " & AppearanceWaived & ", " & _
                         "    tblCalendar.Dismissed = " & Dismissed & ", " & _
                         "    tblCalendar.HearingResults = " & HearingResults & ", " & _
                         "    tblCalendar.Disposition = " & Disposition & ", " & _
                         "    tblCalendar.DOB = " & DOB & ", " & _
                         "    tblCalendar.Minor = " & Minor & ", " & _
                         "    tblCalendar.Sex = " & Sex & ", " & _
                         "    tblCalendar.ClerkName = " & Clerk & ", " & _
                         "    tblCalendar.Judge = " & Judge 
    DoCmd.SetWarnings False
    DoCmd.RunSQL (SQLMove)
    DoCmd.RunSQL (SQLReplace)
    DoCmd.SetWarnings True
End Sub
```

To finish, instead of declaring a `String` variable for each attributes in `tableTemp` that you want to copy, and then assigning some values to them, you can simply omit the declarations and put the attributes dicrectly in the SQL. That will geatly reduce the length of your code as follow:

```
Private Sub Form_Close()

    Dim SQLMove As String
    Dim SQLReplace As String

    SQLMove = "INSERT INTO tblCalendar SELECT * FROM tblTemp"
    SQLReplace = "UPDATE tblCalendar " & _
                 "INNER JOIN tblTemp ON tblCalendar.CourtDate = tblTemp.CourtDate " & _
                         "SET tblCalendar.CountyCaseType = tblTemp.CountyCaseType, " & _
                         "    tblCalendar.CaseNumber = tblTemp.CaseNumber, " & _
                         "    tblCalendar.County = tblTemp.County, " & _
                         "    tblCalendar.FirstName = tblTemp.FirstName, " & _
                         "    tblCalendar.MiddleName = tblTemp.MiddleName, " & _
                         "    tblCalendar.LastName = tblTemp.LastName, " & _
                         "    tblCalendar.Facility = tblTemp.Facility, " & _
                         "    tblCalendar.VOL = tblTemp.VOL, " & _
                         "    tblCalendar.Diagnosis = tblTemp.Diagnosis, " & _
                         "    tblCalendar.AppearanceWaived = tblTemp.AppearanceWaived, " & _
                         "    tblCalendar.Dismissed = tblTemp.Dismissed, " & _
                         "    tblCalendar.HearingResults = tblTemp.HearingResults, " & _
                         "    tblCalendar.Disposition = tblTemp.Disposition, " & _
                         "    tblCalendar.DOB = tblTemp.DOB, " & _
                         "    tblCalendar.Minor = tblTemp.Minor, " & _
                         "    tblCalendar.Sex = tblTemp.Sex, " & _
                         "    tblCalendar.ClerkName = tblTemp.ClerkName, " & _
                         "    tblCalendar.Judge = tblTemp.Judge"
    DoCmd.SetWarnings False
    DoCmd.RunSQL (SQLMove)
    DoCmd.RunSQL (SQLReplace)
    DoCmd.SetWarnings True
End Sub
```

Comment: @Parfait Good point! I confused with the SQLMove query. I will change that in my answer. Thanks

Comment: oh my... @Parfait thank you for reviewing it with me! I put a space before it.

Comment: Wow, thank you for all of that feedback. I've actually been away from work for a few days, so I haven't had a chance to review any of the responses. I'll let you know what happens when I get back into my code. Thanks!

Comment: I've made all the suggested changes and I'm happy to say that there aren't any errors for the code. Thanks to all involved! Unfortunately, when I close the form no changes are reflected in tblCalendar. I'm working on figuring out why, but any suggestions would be greatly appreciated. I'm thinking it might relate to the Primary Key for both tables -- not sure though.

Comment: @BrianH Try to put the code in the `UserForm_QueryClose()` procedure of your form instead of `UserForm_Close`

Comment: @OscarAnythony I figured out what the issue was. It turns out I needed to join the tables by CourtDate AND by CaseNumber in order for the update function to work as intended. Everything seems to be working great now. Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: No problem! I'm glad I could help.

Comment: @BrianH Just to know, did you put the code in the `Form_QueryClose` procedure for it to work? or you left it in the `Form_Close` procedure. Just tell me so that I can update my answer if need to.

Comment: I left it in the Form_Close procedure.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the single quotes from `"Where 'CourtDate = tblCalendar.CourtDate.Value'"`